# Is there a way to iterate through all users in a discord server using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

As the title states, i was wondering if there was a way to iterate through everyone in a server using discord.py? I would like it iterate through all people in the server and perform an action as it were an in range loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way.
Every guild (server) has a list of members stored in discord.Guild.members
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members